# Windows 7 sets removable media (thunms and flash cards) to READ ONLY until you "scan" them 10927

Tags: windows-7

How do I FLAT OUT 100% disable this STUPID functionality that is nothing short of insanely annoying (I deal with a TON of SD cards)

When I insert a new SD card its ALWAYS read only. Non negotiable. the only way around this is to right click the card goto properties tools and then check now (checkdsk basically)

I uncheck everything it says it "fixed" something even though it did absolutely positively NOTHING and now I can remove the memory card and reinsert the card and its now read write.

this is stupid new windows 7 BS crap thing. if I did not love the THUMBS nail view so much in windows 7 I would dump it and go back to XP for which I can whip into doing as I command.

Grrr

it randomly does this when it does not like the card or what happens to the card (removal etc..)

NO i do not "safely" remove and never will what a total pain. never had to in XP. I just make sure no data is moving and yank the card.

SO how do I completely DISABLE this "feature" in windows 7 ?

thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I've never seen the behavior you're mentioning - normally when Windows 7 detects file system trouble (and there is file system trouble, even though you can't see what it's fixed. In the future you might sate your curiosity by running `chkdsk /f` on it at the command line so you can see the output), it prompts you to chkdsk the card when it's inserted but doesn't force you to do so. Just pressing "Cancel" on the warning dialog will allow you to use the card normally.

I suppose it is possible that Windows will behave this way only when there is severe filesystem damage, such that it determines that it would be dangerous to write to the card (writing to a damaged filesystem could potentially, in some cases even likely, destroy data currently in place). However, filesystem damage to this extent should not happen on a regular basis. Are you certain that you're not removing the cards while data is being written? does it not behave this way if you use the Safely Eject option? (which, in current versions of Windows, is not really necessary - Windows disables write caching to flash storage devices by default, so that interactions are 'atomic', meaning that when visible writing finishes the file system should always be in a safe state. Windows refers to this as "Optimize for fast removal", there is also an "Optimize for best performance" option that will re-enable write caching resulting in faster write speeds, at the penalty that you *must* use the safely remove hardware option).

My first suspicion here is that the memory cards are malfunctioning or have seriously faulted file systems, or your card reader is malfunctioning or has unusual drivers. As a first troubleshooting step you could try finding the latest drivers for your card reader and reformatting the affected cards in order to ensure a clean filesystem.

Comment: if fixes nothing. it finds no errors. No there is not file system trouble. I put it in my xp machine did a full scandisk on it put it back in the 7 machine STILL won't allow write options UNTIL I scan it in windows 7. its definately a windpws 7 thing. I will try the checkdsk /f next time. Any particular reason I can not press ENTER when typing this reply? pressing enter is like click save edits. Very annoying :-) it does it to 100% of all my memory cards (some 15 of them) the "first" time windows 7 see's them. next time it does it I will try to record it.

Comment: OK found a BRAND NEW kingston 2gb card the machine has never seen before. plugged it into the SD slot. card is READ ONLY. I can not add files (no files on it to try and delete) man this ENTER crap is annoying - so I run a chkdsk /f and it says NO problems found with file system. NOW it can write to the card. it appears the "SIMPLE ACT" of running chkdsk "registers" the card as "now ok" and it does not do the read only crap anymore. I only have one machine running 7 so I can't presume all will do this. anytime I insert a new SD card (brand new or used) it is read only until I do a scan. then ok

Comment: BTW it never prompts me to do ANYTHING. the card literally behaves like I Have the lock switch engaged. windows 7 puts it in "read only" mode. once I run a scan (right click or from cmd) it finds NO errors but now on reinsertion of the card it behaves normally. I only noticed this when I attempted to DELETE files and it error'd with the read only error message. I did a google search and found someone who had fixed it by "scanning" I did this and it went away even though it found no errors. now is months later and its annoying me (got a few new cards) so hoping I could disable this "feature"

Comment: This is not a feature of Windows, something is wrong with your machine. Please try updating drivers for your card reader, go to the website of the manufacturer of the computer and go to the Downloads or Drivers section and follow the prompts. Once you have run the driver update reboot your computer and see if the problem persists. If it does, we may have few choices but trying a reinstallation of Windows. One diagnostic measure would be to find or borrow a USB card reader and see if it demonstrates the same behaviour.